# Is the space of subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ with the Hausdorff metric separable?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let M be the Metric Space whose "points" are the Closed and Bounded subsets of a finite dimensional Euclidean Space and whose "distance function" is the Metric defined by Hausdorff for such point sets. Is M separable?

Comment: Wait, why the negative response? This seems like a reasonable question.

Comment: @NoahSchweber See the discussion on http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question.  This is very important to keep a decent level of discussions on the site (but apparently the OP has got away with this quite a few times already).

Comment: @NoahSchweber This is a good question, but I think it could phrased a little more clearly.  For instance, the "distance function" the OP is referring to is unbeknownst to me (it would be nice if it were included).  It would be helpful too if the OP mentioned what they've tried and their thoughts on the problem.

Comment: @garabedgulbenkian To be sure (and perhaps suggest a more precise phrasing): are you asking if the set of compact subsets of $\Bbb R^n$, endowed with the [Hausdorff-Pompieu distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance), is a separable metric space?

Comment: Yes. That is what I am asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is separable - in fact, it has a countable dense subset consisting entirely of finite sets!

*Exercise*. Let $C$ be a closed bounded set, and $N\subseteq C$ such that for each $c\in C$, there is an $n\in N$ such that $d(n, c)<\epsilon$. Then the Hausdorff distance between $N$ and $C$ is $<\epsilon$.

*Such an $N$ is sometimes called an "$\epsilon$-dense subset" of $C$, or "$\epsilon$-net."*

*Exercise*. Using the previous, show that the set $$\mathcal{F}=\{N: N\subseteq\mathbb{Q}^n\mbox{ is finite }\}$$ is dense in the space of closed bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Note that it's not quite one line - plenty of closed bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ don't contain any rational points at all! So it takes a bit of thought.

---

EDIT: in response to a comment below, let me add an even simpler proof sketch:

For a given $\epsilon>0$, divide the plane into $\epsilon$-squares: let $$S_\epsilon(a, b)=[a\epsilon, (a+1)\epsilon)\times[b\epsilon, (b+1)\epsilon)$$ for $a, b$ integers. Let $q^\epsilon_{a, b}$ be a rational point in $S_\epsilon(a, b)$. Now for $X\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ bounded, let $$A_\epsilon(X)=\{q^\epsilon_{a, b}: X\cap S_\epsilon(a, b)\not=\emptyset\},$$ that is, we "mark" each box which $X$ hits.

Since $X$ is bounded, the set $A_\epsilon(X)$ is finite; and it's not hard to bound the Hausdorff distance between $A_\epsilon(X)$ and $X$, and show that it goes to zero as $\epsilon\rightarrow0$. So the set of finite sets of rational points is a dense set in this metric, and is clearly countable.

Comment: Similarly, the *Gromov-Hausdorff metric* on the set of compact metric spaces modulo isometry is separable, via finite metric spaces with rational distances.

Comment: The first term that I learned for a set like $N$ is $\epsilon$-*net*.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Makes sense, I've added it. (I actually haven't heard it before.)

Comment: The topology the Hausdorff metric generates is actually also known as the Vietoris topology, and for this it's also quite easy to see the separability. But this comes at a cost: prove that the metric topology and it coincide. The benefit is that in the Vietoris topology is often easier to some properties like connectedness etc.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Good point (and for the OP and anyone interested, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertopology and http://www.heldermann-verlag.de/jca/jca01/jca01013.pdf).

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Thanks a lot for your response. I am sorry not to have included a more precise definition of the Hausdorff Metric but  I am not too good at entering from my keyboard  some of the mathematical symbolism which occurs in that definition. The 1957 Chelsea Publishing Co. Edition of an English translation of  Hausdorff's  book "Mengenlehre" contains this definition in Section 28 of Chapter 6.

Comment: @NoahSchweber : May I ask you, is there any reference for these exercises? for the result that the space of subsets of R^n is separable? Could you please suggest me any Textbook or paper as a reference?

Comment: @Yi-HsuanLin First of all, it's not the space of subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$, just the *compact* (= closed and bounded) ones. To answer your question, I don't know a resource for it, but it is very easy to prove - I've edited with a sketch of a simpler proof than what I wrote initially.

Comment: @NoahSchweber If we consider only finite sets, i.e. the space of all finite subsets of $R^n$, this space is still separable, right? It seems that your proof still applies. Did I miss anything?

Comment: @Yi-HsuanLin Yes, that subspace is also separable.